# API Method to check if value in a string variable is positive numeric value

Tags: java

I have a String variable in java,

```
String strNum = "-90.29";
```

Apart from `regex`, is there any API method available to check if `strNum` contains a valid positive decimal value.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Why cant u just convert it to float and check. 'Float.parse(..)'

Comment: I don't think there are any. Because this looks like a very trivial task to be included in any API.

Comment: `if (new BigDecimal(strNum).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0)`

Comment: `boolean isPositive = strNum.charAt(0) != '-';`

Comment: `if (strNum.trim().startsWith("-") || !strNum.trim().contains(".") || strNum.chars().filter(num -> num == '.').count() != 1) { // Not Valid } else { // Is Valid }`. The `strNum.trim().startsWith("-")` and `!strNum.trim().contains(".")` are self explanatory. The `strNum.chars().filter(num -> num == '.').count()` code counts the number of dots (.) in string value so as to ensure there is only one of them. No RegEx used however, this is soooo much easier with Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Apaches commons.lang.math like (null-safe):

```
NumberUtils.toScaledBigDecimal(strNum).signum() == 1
```

Comment: *contains a valid positive **decimal** value*?